# Congratulations DMGregory!

Tags: discussion

Our great friend [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) has reached 100,002 reputation! With 2.9~ million people reached and 2,279 answers, let’s **give him a big round of applause!** He’s been with Stack for over 7 years. Great job!

Answer with some of your favorite things he's done (jokes, problem-solving, [shining wit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19?m=57659143#57659143), etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Awww, thank you! I hope I've been useful to you!

> Answer with some of your favorite things he's done

Definitely this:

[image: Can squirrel be directly integrated?]

[image: Deleted answer]

It's all just been downhill from there.

Answer (score 4):

I remember when DMGregory and I had an interesting conversation about aliens and what creatures can get into cars (we are in yellow):

[image: Funny Conversation]

But, I would say I was right, because if my dog can get into my car (I don't know how) then I'm *pretty certain* an alien could too.

Comment: I like your name change from 'noobprogrammer' to 'OKprogrammer' since that conversation.

Comment: Yep. I'm OK now, I suppose. ;)